# d3 General Update Pattern

Tags: d3.js

I just mimic the code [d3 update pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234) trying to render some rect with updated data
here is my code.

```
            function update(data){
                var r = g.selectAll("rect").data(data,function(d){return (d)});

                r.exit().attr("class","exit").remove()

                r
                .attr("class","update")
                .attr("x",(d, i) =>{return i* (50+interval)})
                .attr("y", (d)=>{ return y(d)})
                .attr("width", "20px")
                .transition(t)
                .attr("height",( d => {  return  height-padding.top-padding.bottom-y(d);}))

                r.enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", "20px")
                .attr("class","new")
                .attr("x",(d, i) =>{  return i * (50+interval)})
                .attr("y", (d)=>{return y(d)})
                .attr("height",( d => {  return  height-padding.top-padding.bottom-y(d);}))

    
            }
```

then I call the update function twice

```
            update([3,2,1,5,4,10,9,7,8,6])
            setTimeout(()=>{update([2,3,1,5,4,10,9,7,8,6])},1000)
```

Expected: only the first and second rect will be rerendered and set class "new", but in fact, all the rect will be set class "new" .

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/xwyzsn/pen/YzZLdLN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enter/exit pattern works when the data is an array of identified objects.
Replace this code:

```
var r = g.selectAll("rect").data(data,function(d){return (d)});
```

with:

```
const _data = data.map((v,i) => ({id: i, value: v}));
const r = g.selectAll("rect").data(_data,d => d.id);
```

The D3 will identify each object and update it accordingly instead of replacing with a new one.

See it's working in a [pen](https://codepen.io/mrovinsky/pen/BaWxboa)

**UPD:**
If you want to highlight the items whose values have been changed, you can save the current value in an attribute of a newly added item:

```
r.enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr('cur-value', d => d.value)
  ...
```

then, on update, query the value and compare with the one in datum:

```
r.attr("class","update")
  ...
  .each(function(d) {
    const rect = d3.select(this);
    const prevValue = parseInt(rect.attr('cur-value'));
    rect.attr('cur-value', d.value);
    rect.style('fill', prevValue === d.value ? 'black' : 'red')
  });
```

You can see it's working in the updated pen.

Comment: thank you, It works! but I want to know how can I only color the column with those changed data and keep others in the original color.